# AS3 - Create a grid with customizable row and col values based on array length?

Tags: actionscript-3, layout, grid, grid-layout

I'm working on a Layout plugin to place all items added to the the **parent** object in a grid formation. I want to be able to set the column, row, padding values. I push all child objects into an array and I loop these with a **for** loop. I already tried to use a double for loop to check on wich position the objects need to be placed but that always gave me **index out of bounds** errors. Currently I'm using this code to set up my grid formation:

```
    var COLUMNS:int = vars.columns;
    var PADDING:Number = 10;


    for(var i:int = 0; i < childs.length; i++)
    {
        childs[i].x = (i % COLUMNS) * (childs[i].width + PADDING);
        childs[i].y = int(i / COLUMNS) * (childs[i].height + PADDING);
    }
```

and here is an example of how I'm using this plugin:
**NOTE: The Draw objects just return a sprite with the dimensions of 150x150**

```
    var container:Sprite = new Sprite();
    var obj1:Draw = new Draw({x:0 ,y:0 ,width:_width,height:_height, color:Constants.GREEN});
    var obj2:Draw = new Draw({x:0 ,y:0 ,width:_width,height:_height, color:0x2C2C2C});
    var obj3:Draw = new Draw({x:0 ,y:0 ,width:_width,height:_height, color:Constants.BLACK});
    var obj4:Draw = new Draw({x:0 ,y:0 ,width:_width,height:_height, color:Constants.GREEN});
    var obj5:Draw = new Draw({x:0 ,y:0 ,width:_width,height:_height, color:Constants.GREEN});
    var obj6:Draw = new Draw({x:0 ,y:0 ,width:_width,height:_height, color:0x2C2C2C});
    var obj7:Draw = new Draw({x:0 ,y:0 ,width:_width,height:_height, color:Constants.BLACK});
    var obj8:Draw = new Draw({x:0 ,y:0 ,width:_width,height:_height, color:Constants.GREEN});
    var obj9:Draw = new Draw({x:0 ,y:0 ,width:_width,height:_height, color:Constants.GREEN});

    addChild(container);
    container.addChild(obj1);
    container.addChild(obj2);
    container.addChild(obj3);
    container.addChild(obj4);
    container.addChild(obj5);
    container.addChild(obj6);
    container.addChild(obj7);
    container.addChild(obj9);

    Layout.setLayout(new GridLayout(container, {columns:4, rows:10, spacing:2}));
```

Anyone got any idea on how to create a better grid loop with **fixed columns, rows, spacing where all the objects are retrieved by an earlier filled array?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found how I could make this work!
for the people who are interessed:

**1) check before drawing the grid**

```
    var cols:int = vars.columns;
    var rows:int = vars.rows;
    var spacing:int = vars.spacing;


    if((cols * rows) >= childs.length) {
        drawComplexGrid(rows, cols, spacing);
    } else {
        var val:int = Math.max(rows, cols);
        drawComplexGrid(val,(childs.length/val), spacing);
    }
```

**2) Actually drawing the grid and checking if the array is empty or not (array childs is already filled with a few "Draw" objects**

```
private function drawComplexGrid(rows:int, cols:int, spacing:int):void
{
    for (var py:int = 0; py <rows; py++)
    {
        for (var px:int = 0; px <cols; px++)
        {
            if(childs.length > 0)
            {
                var child:* = childs.shift();

                child.x = (child.width + spacing) * px;
                child.y = (child.height + spacing) * py;

            } else {
                break;
            }

        }
    }
}
```